# Product catalogue in WordPress

Tags: plugins, theme-development

I need to create a product catalogue that contains around 15 categories and each of them have about 10-20 products. There's no problem in doing that with some plugins, but they have limited customization.

How can I achieve this and also be able to have my own custom CSS applied to it?

P.S. I am doing this on my custom theme.

Comment: Is this a custom child theme?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with products and product catagories, I would recommend WooCommerce. It's free has it's own classes, so you can apply your own custom CSS to it.